# Is it possible to download Mozilla Firefox without using another browser?

Tags: windows, firefox

Firefox used to operate an FTP server to download binaries. When they moved over to AWS, [they removed FTP access](http://web.archive.org/web/20160310190838/https://blog.mozilla.org/it/2015/07/27/product-delivery-migration-what-is-changing-when-its-changing-and-the-impacts/). As far as I can tell, the only way to obtain Firefox is to download the installer stub which then downloads it.

Is there another way to download the *full* latest Firefox binary without using a browser or curl?

Comment: What's wrong with using cURL?

Comment: I assume you're on Windows, since it's the only modern OS that doesn't let you install it via a package manager (apt, yum, etc.) Is this correct?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, cURL is not installed on a default Windows installation. I can't believe they shut down anonymous FTP. It's going the way of Gopher and WAIS.

Comment: @Joseph Sible, that is correct.

Comment: "cURL is not installed on a default Windows installation." Ok, how about using Powershell's Invoke-WebRequest (which is a cURL/WGet analogue)?

Comment: IIRC bitstransfer in PS allows HTTPS, or WebRequest as Techie has suggested.

Comment: What's wrong with using HTTP at all? And nearly every modern (or less than modern) system has a browser - I mean, IE's gotta be good for *something* right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PowerShell: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output` or `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)`. Source: https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell

Answer (score 1):

TLDR:

> wget -O FirefoxSetup.exe "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win64&lang=en-US"

On the [Mozilla FTP directory](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/latest/README.txt), they have included an instruction on how to download Firefox using wget. I have included it below:

```
Please use download.mozilla.org to retrieve the latest Firefox release. 

For example, if you wish to download the US English installer for Windows (32bit)
the url is
   https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US

This could be pasted into the location bar of a browser, or used with curl or wget,  e.g. 
wget -O FirefoxSetup.exe "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US"

For other operating systems replace 'os=win' with:
   Windows 64bit              os=win64
   OS X                       os=osx
   Linux x86_64               os=linux64
   Linux i686                 os=linux

For other languages replace 'lang=en-US' with:
   Acholi                     lang=ach
   Afrikaans                  lang=af
   Albanian                   lang=sq
   Arabic                     lang=ar
   Aragonese                  lang=an
   Armenian                   lang=hy-AM
   Assamese                   lang=as
   Asturian                   lang=ast
   Azerbaijani                lang=az
   Basque                     lang=eu
   Belarusian                 lang=be
   Bengali (Bangladesh)       lang=bn-BD
   Bengali (India)            lang=bn-IN
   Bosnian                    lang=bs
   Breton                     lang=br
   Bulgarian                  lang=bg
   Catalan                    lang=ca
   Chinese (Simplified)       lang=zh-CN
   Chinese (Traditional)      lang=zh-TW
   Croatian                   lang=hr
   Czech                      lang=cs
   Danish                     lang=da
   Dutch                      lang=nl
   English (British)          lang=en-GB
   English (South African)    lang=en-ZA
   Esperanto                  lang=eo
   Estonian                   lang=et
   Finnish                    lang=fi
   French                     lang=fr
   Frisian                    lang=fy-NL
   Fulah                      lang=ff
   Gaelic (Scotland)          lang=gd
   Galician                   lang=gl
   German                     lang=de
   Greek                      lang=el
   Gujarati (India)           lang=gu-IN
   Hebrew                     lang=he
   Hindi (India)              lang=hi-IN
   Hungarian                  lang=hu
   Icelandic                  lang=is
   Indonesian                 lang=id
   Irish                      lang=ga-IE
   Italian                    lang=it
   Kannada                    lang=kn
   Kazakh                     lang=kk
   Khmer                      lang=km
   Korean                     lang=ko
   Latvian                    lang=lv
   Ligurian                   lang=lij
   Lithuanian                 lang=lt
   Lower Sorbian              lang=dsb
   Macedonian                 lang=mk
   Maithili                   lang=mai
   Malay                      lang=ms
   Malayalam                  lang=ml
   Marathi                    lang=mr
   Norwegian (BokmÃ¥l)        lang=nb-NO
   Norwegian (Nynorsk)        lang=nn-NO
   Oriya                      lang=or
   Persian                    lang=fa
   Polish                     lang=pl
   Portuguese (Brazilian)     lang=pt-BR
   Portuguese (Portugal)      lang=pt-PT
   Punjabi (India)            lang=pa-IN
   Romanian                   lang=ro
   Romansh                    lang=rm
   Russian                    lang=ru
   Serbian                    lang=sr
   Sinhala                    lang=si
   Slovak                     lang=sk
   Slovenian                  lang=sl
   Songhai                    lang=son
   Spanish (Argentina)        lang=es-AR
   Spanish (Chile)            lang=es-CL
   Spanish (Mexico)           lang=es-MX
   Spanish (Spain)            lang=es-ES
   Swedish                    lang=sv-SE
   Tamil                      lang=ta
   Telugu                     lang=te
   Thai                       lang=th
   Turkish                    lang=tr
   Ukrainian                  lang=uk
   Upper Sorbian              lang=hsb
   Uzbek                      lang=uz
   Vietnamese                 lang=vi
   Welsh                      lang=cy
   Xhosa                      lang=xh


Mozilla Release Engineering
Email: release-engineering@lists.mozilla.org
Web:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla.release.engineering
``
```

Answer (score -1):

Google is very helpful in this matter.  Here is a link to the FTP for Firefox releases.  It contains all public Firefox releases at the time of this writing and future/beta releases so it appears this is what they're using now.  Each respective release directory contains the binary you're looking for (the 45MB version, not the 240KB stub).

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Sure - there are other ways to download it.  You mentioned cURL; if this is a programming question, ask it on StackOverflow and be specific (what language, what have you tried, etc). Otherwise, we'll need to know what you're trying to accomplish because as it stands, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: you provided an https link to a web server, not an ftp server. you cannot connect to that server via ftp.